# Facebook OAuthException: The access token could not be decrypted

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a running application that does scheduled wall posts to one of their friends on behalf of the user.

The application was running fine for quite some time but recently quiet a few of the users have reported the messages not being posted.

The logs shows

```
OAuthException: The access token could not be decrypted.
```

Even if the user revisits the application and resets their Access token the exception persists.

What may be the root of the error and ways to work around it?

Comment: Is it still working for any users?  I know that last Friday (when Facebook went public), all access tokens for all of my apps were revoked.  I had to delete all my stored access tokens and required all my users to "authorize" the app again.  If I tried to exchange the token, it failed.  But simply repeating the authorization process (which won't require any real action since the app is authorized already, simply a click of link will do the trick) gave me a new, valid access token.

Comment: How did you know that all the access tokens had been revoked? Did you get any exceptions?

Comment: I used the access token debugger and found that every single token I had was no longer valid.  I just put 2 and 2 together from there.  Since this happened on the day they went public, and I had about 7 apps.  All of my access tokens with all 7 apps were no longer valid.

Answer (score 13):

If you get the following error message when making HTTP requests to the Facebook API:

```
{
  "error": {
       "message": "The access token could not be decrypted",
       "type": "OAuthException",
       "code": 190
  }
}
```

it means that **the access token you are sending to Facebook when you make the HTTP request is *NOT* valid.**

If you look at the **HTTP response headers** you will see a field like this:

```
WWW-Authenticate:OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_token" "The access token could not be decrypted"
```

I was receiving the error above because I was sending an access token that was 1 character shorter than what was the valid one.
After comparing the access token persisted with the one I was sending I discovered this mistake.

You can check the validity of the OAuth 2.0 access token (bearer token) used on Facebook with the [Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token).

Comment: Had the same issue. The form field for the token on Facebook could be bigger.

Answer (score 5):

Facebook tokens are increasing in size and are no more limitated to 255 chars, so the way you store them may result in an exception if you use a variable or a database field with limited sizes.

This is specified in the last section of this Facebook doc : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

> **Sizes**
>
> Expect that the size of all types of access tokens will change over time as Facebook makes changes to what is stored in them and how they are encoded. You can expect that they will grow and shrink over time. Please use a variable length data type without a specific maximum size to store access tokens.

For exemple to store tokens in a SQL you may avoid the use of VARCHAR and use TEXT or BLOB instead

Comment: This solved my issue. I stored only 120 characters in my database. +1

Answer (score 1):

This may because token trim before save in database. or field size is less then token charter size. check once in {variable} table for correct and full token.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by the accessToken not containing the userID when I made a request for "me" (which, I assume, attempts to determine the userID from the token).

Token debugger response:

```
App ID: 
<ID> :   <app>
User ID: Unknown
Issued:  Unknown
Expires: 1339171200 (in about an hour)
Valid:   True
Origin:  Web
Scopes:
```

To fix the problem, instead of requesting 'me', I requested the profile for the userID, which I had access to from the authResponse directly.

Answer (score 0):

This error often happens when access token length is not correct. Verify the format of the token.