# Facebook OauthException code 190 "The Access Token Could Not Be Decrypted"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I am developing an android web app that uses login with facebook functionality. Using the facebook login tutorials I was able to authenticate and create the session on the client side (android). I obtain the access token then forward it to the server so that I can obtain the user profile on the server and start the server session.

The problem is that whenever I try to call the Facebook graph for /me I get that OauthException code 190 that the access token could not be decrypted. I have been reading around and people suggest that this message means the access token is invalid.

I am sure it is not expired because I use it directly after obtaining it.
 I also checked the access token debugger. It does not return an error message, it returns the developers.facebook.com url (weird, right?) .

I am lost about where to go from here. I have spent almost 5 days now just reading and trying to debug with no success.

I appreciate any ideas/suggestions.

Thanks

EDIT:

I was able to perform a "/me" request from android, and the response was exactly what I was looking for, when I do it from the server it does not work. I still cannot think of the cause of this issue.

Comment: It obviously your access token is corrupted/truncated when perform http request, you should double check your code and debug/print out the access token in the line your code implement the http request, kindly read this threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071412/error-the-access-token-could-not-be-decrypted and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742445/facebook-oauthexception-the-access-token-could-not-be-decrypted

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I am not sure how the access token can be corrupted or truncated. I am not using a database to store it. I simply send it as an HTTP POST variable. Do POST variables have size limit that the access token is exceeding?

Comment: I'm not doing server side but i think you can read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364840/what-is-the-size-limit-of-a-post-request. Also as i said, you should print out what data you sent as HTTP POST variables. If you can't perform https sniffer, you can still change the link from HTTPS to HTTP and sniffing the network traffic to know what header, data and url is exactly sent. Of course you will get "You must use https:// when passing an access token" error but it doesn't matter because your purpose is sniffing the data you sent. After that, debug the access token you sniff.

Comment: The problem turned out to be from a database i was performing inside a try block that contains the facebook request. So I thought the facebook request was not performing. Everything is working fine now. Thanks for your interest and help.